# Implement Firebase data management in the Front-End vs. Back-End

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication

I'm a quite new JavaScript developer, coming from the Embedded Systems area, i.e., algorithms and programming basic concepts are not an issue for me, but some concepts of web development (front/back end) are still new to me, and many doubts often come up.

Going directly to my question, I'm currently developing a basic HTML + JS application where the user must login to get access to a "private" area; once logged-in, it is possible to perform many service requests and see other users requests, being more or less an "intranet" system.

I'm using **Firebase Firestore** as the database, and adopting two approaches to comunicate with the database:

-For **user authentication management (log-in and sign-up processes)**, I'm taking advantage of the **"front-end"** JS modules provided by Firebase, using the login/password method with the e-mail link confirmation feature activated. Once an auth request is sent, the firebase app returns a token, and based on this token a session cookie is generated, granting access to the private area. This way, I don't need to manage most of the auth / account validation steps in my back-end part.

-For **any other database operations (firestore read & write)**, I'm using the 'firebase-admin' SDK in conjunction with my back-end implementation, in a way that all the requests are validated with the session cookie before being actually performed. The back-end has access to a service account JSON "key", which gives it total read & write access to the whole database.

Finally, the questions are:

-Is it acceptable or conventional to use both approaches, front-end and back-end, to manage the firebase application?

-Once all the firestore data is being managed in the back-end side, and all the read/write/privilege rules are managed there, is it correct the correct approach to set the security rules to block everything, as follows? (considering that firebase-admin bypasses everything from the back-end side, not being affected)

```
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /{document=**} {
      allow read, write: if false;
    }
  }
}
```

Best regards, and please let me know if I was clear in my doubts :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Combining front-end and back-end code when using Firestore (or other Firebase modules) is quite normal. Performing all data access through the Admin SDK (while not necessary) is a completely acceptable approach too. Setting the rules to not allow any direct access from client-side SDKs (or with ID tokens through the REST APIs) is indeed a logical step in this scenario.

On thing to realize is that your **code** is now responsible for ensuring all data is authorized, while in cases where you use client-side Firebase SDKs it is the  **security rules** that perform access control.

Comment: Thanks, Frank! I know this question may sound really trivial, but you know... begginers' doubts :).
In fact, this approach is functional, and a good opportunity to work the front-end and back-end in my project.
Best regards!